# How can I create an auto incrementing Id in a temp table?

Tags: sql-server

I created a temp table in my stored procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl (
        [Id]         INT,
        [Correct]    BIT     
        )
```

How can I populate this table with an autogenerated increasing number for the Id and this data:

```
SELECT Correct FROM question
INNER JOIN answer
ON    (question.questionId = answer.questionId)
WHERE question.questionid = 25
ORDER BY answer.answerId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following format:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl (
        [Id]         INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        [Correct]    BIT     
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Correct bit
)
```

this will create auto inc field in your table

Answer (score 1):

Without `IDENTITY` you can try this

```
SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY answer.answerId) AS Id, Correct
FROM        question INNER JOIN 
            answer ON (question.questionId = answer.questionId)
WHERE       question.questionid = 25
ORDER BY    answer.answerId
```